# Polynomial time problems with provably high degree time complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, polynomial-time

For any integer $k$, does there exist a decision problem in $\textbf P$ that can be proven to require $\Omega(n^k)$ steps?

Comment: Yes. This follows from the time hierarchy theorem.

Comment: Is the proof constructive? Can you find a concrete problem for any $k$?

Comment: The problem is deciding whether a given Turing machine halts on a given string of length $n$ in time $n^k$.

Comment: A more concrete example is, given a graph, to determine whether or not there exists a $k$-clique for a constant $k$. (observe that this is essentially a weaker version of the time-hierarchy theorem)

Comment: @quicksort I'm pretty sure that the complexity of k-clique is an open poroblem

Comment: @Ariel Are you sure? I might be wrong, but for each $k$ there should be values of $n$ large enough that the only fasiable strategy is to try everything. Even a lower bound of $n^{poly(k)}$ would answer OP's question.

Comment: @quicksort Such a bound would imply $P\neq NP$.

Comment: for a *constant* $k$?

Comment: @quicksort Yes. Suppose such a bound exists, i.e. for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ k-clique requires time $\Omega(n^k)$. If P=NP then you can solve clique in $O(n^\alpha)$ time, which means that for $k>\alpha$ your bound does not hold.

Comment: 3-clique is solvable in time $O(n^{2.4})$ by squaring the adjacency matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time hierarchy theorem, proved by diagonalization, shows that for every reasonable function $f$ there exists a problem solvable in $O(f(n))$ but not in $o(f(n)/\log f(n))$. One such problem is, given a Turing machine and in input $x$, to determine whether the machine halts in $x$ within $f(|x|)$ steps. In your case, you can choose $f(n) = n^k \log n$ to obtain a problem solvable in $O(n^k \log n)$ but not in $o(n^k)$.